# Вопрос по сбору данных (Python)

Tags: python

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поступить при такой ситуации. Или дать направление что читать и куда копать.
Существует 3 брокерские базы, которые разными методами, где-то через библиотеки, где-то через вебсокеты собирают одинаковые списки данных по одинаковым объектам. Затем эти данные объединяются и среди одинаковых объектов всех трех баз, проводится сравнение стоимости. Если стоимость объекта на одной из таких баз сильно отличается от двух других, то ее дальнейшее рассмотрение должно идти отдельным потоком.

```
my_list1 = [[a,1][b,2][c,5][d,6]]
my_list2 = [[a,1][b,1][c,1][d,3]]
my_list3 = [[a,4][b,2][c,3][d,1]]
```

Дальше идет ряд операций нудных и не интересны и в конце концов получаются некоторые данные в `big_list`, которые формируются из трех баз `my_list`. Количество элементов во внутренних списках может меняться. Можно быть только `a` или наоборот все 4 буквы.
Например:

```
big_list = [[a,4], [b,2], [...]]
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы каждый раз если `a` равняется определенному значению, запускался отдельный поток функции run_me(a,4), затем также происходило со всеми элементами которые остались.
Что изучать `thread`?

Comment: У вас там внутри списков словари? И ключ - строка? А то ведь такие структуры данных не скомпилируются

Comment: А вообще архитектура будет зависеть от сценария использования. Если это всё постоянно происходит, то, возможно, лучше писать в базу, откуда отдельно запущенный скрипт будет разгребать задания на обработку.

Comment: Пробывал так. Очень неудобно.

Comment: Прошу прощения, исправил. Нет строки, конечно

Comment: Ну так то можете попробовать `thread`, проблема в том, что запуск `thread` ради обработки одного элемента - это очень накладно. Но для начала можете попробовать и так.

Comment: почему не делать все последовательно? Сначало найдите все объекты с нужным значением `res = [x for x in big_list if x[1] = 4]`, потом параллельно запустите `run_me` для этих объектов.

Comment: Скорость принятия решения имеет очень высокое значение. Последовательно, очень долго. Там сотни вариаций и чем быстрее будет найдена первая подходящая, тем лучше.

Comment: Не факт, что он будет один. Элементов каждый раз разное количество.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно стоит рассмотреть асинхронный код - `asyncio` [ссылка](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html), `concurrent.futures` [ссылка](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) и [ссылка](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor).

Возможный Ваш код:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import asyncio

def something(key, value):
    pass

async def common_thing(key, value):
    await asyncio.sleep(0)


async def main():
    pattern = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, }
    big_data = dict([['a', 4], ['b', 2], ])
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executer:
        futures = {
            executer.submit(something, key, value)
            for key, value in big_data.items()
            if pattern.get(key) == value
        }
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            result = future.result()
            # something with result
    
    tasks = {
        asyncio.create_task(common_thing(key, value))
        for key, value in big_data.items()
        if pattern.get(key) == value
    }

    for task in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        result = await task
        # something with result
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам за пример. Из него я понял, я ничего не знаю про Python. Пойду разбирать)

Comment: @Antony Пожалуйста! Удачи и успехов Вам в изучение Python!